# Gazebo & Ardupilot installation for drone modelling on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: software-installation

Does Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS Jammy main supports ROS/ROS2?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.